# Silly JS comparison

Tags: javascript, comparison

I was evaluating something in the console today and was messing around when I typed and became curious about the following:

`1 === 1 === 1` evaluates to `false`

but

`1 == 1 == 1` evaluates to `true`

Is the first comparison trying to evaluate the type of `1 === 1` as a whole?

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: 1'st says 1 != boolean true, but the
2nd converts boolean true to 1

Comment: [1 === 1 === 1 => true === 1 => false] and [x = true; x == 1 => true] http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: sure, that makes sense. That would also mean `0 == 0 == 1` would be true as well then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the `==` attempts type conversions whereas the `===` does not.

The order of evaluation of both examples is the same, and goes like this:

```
(1 === 1) === 1
(1 == 1) == 1
```

So the first `==` or `===` comparison is done and its result is used as the operand for the second `==` or `===`. Like this:

```
(1 === 1) === 1
//  v         v
  (true)  === 1


(1 == 1) == 1
//  v       v
  (true) == 1
```

So you can see that we now are really talking about:

```
true === 1
```

versus

```
true == 1
```

So the different results stems from the fact that as I mentioned above, the `===` will not attempt to convert any types, while the `==` will try to convert them to matching types.

So without the conversion, the `true === 1` is obviously going to be `false` since they're not the same value, but in the case of `true == 1`, the `true` gets converted to a number, and a numeric conversion of the value `true` always ends up as the number `1`, so now this:

```
true == 1
```

is converted to this:

```
1 == 1
```

which is clearly true.

So the full walkthrough goes like this:

```
(1 == 1) == 1
//  v       v
  (true) == 1
//  v       v
    1    == 1
```